# Dynamically referring to cells in a formula using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to write a macro that populates column H with the concatenation of columns B and C but can't figure out how to refer to the cells in columns B and C. The problem is with:

```
Selection.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(Range("B" & i) & Range("C" & i))"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Here's the whole code.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
    iLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("g10000").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To iLastRow
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i).Select
        Selection.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(Range("B" & i) & Range("C" & i))"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `"=CONCATENATE(B" & i & ",C" & i & ")"`

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This Code will work.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
iLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("g10000").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To iLastRow
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
         .Cells(i, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(i, 3).Value
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```